# Load html in webview when app is in background

Tags: android, webview, background-process, foreground-service, wakelock

I have a webview which loads page from our local server and executes JS function. Everything works fine till the app goes background *(Android 8 and above)*.

I use foreground service to keep the other features of the app running but the webpage does not load but JS function executes on an already open page.

The webview should be up-to-date when the app comes to foreground again.

This is a **voice based** application and contents on screen keeps updating as user progresses with his task.