# React native, Invoke app in background from quite state to render webview in ui

Tags: android, react-native

I'm creating an app which will do web scrapping to fetch some details of user. I also want to run it background so if user didn't open app for few days we can update the content by sending silent notification. I implement the silent notification by using `react-native-firebase` and it's working, but I unable to render ui with to open web-view in background and unable to find any documentation for it. I want that when I send silent notification app invoke in background and render some components to scrap the data from web-view is there any way to do that?

Comment: Join the club.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69121597/load-html-in-webview-when-app-is-in-background

Comment: did you find any solution? XD @Immanuel

Comment: No mate!! A work around would be stack up events that you need (with a set limit) and execute them when the app comes to the foreground!